# Webpack-dev-server hot-reload with react-router

Tags: webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I use yeoman to set up my project with react and webpack.
Then, I manually added react-router to the project.
The hot-reload works fine until I have paths.

So in my index.js, I have

```
<Provider store={store}>
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
    <Route path="/app" component={Nav}>
      <Route path="/app/payable/export" component={Export}/>
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
</Router>
```

The hot-reload works fine for components: App and Dashboard because there path is just "/".

But the hot-reload doesn't work for Export.
I got this error:

```
http://localhost:9300/app/payable/assets/31f035eb918b53b2078f.hot-update.json 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems it is appending the route path in the resource path, but webpack only generates hot-reload files under "/assets/".
However, if I use hashHistory in react-router, I don't have problem. Only when I use broswerHistory.

Here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../src');
...
{
publicPath: '/assets/',
srcPath: srcPath
}
```

Comment: Also, if I go to localhost:9300/, I can see the app, and the routing is working normally, e.g. localhost:9300/app/payable/export. However, if I type that url and hit enter, it complains about localhost:9300/app/payable/export/assets/app.js not found. It tries to find the /assets/app.js under the path of the route, which is not right.